# Simple question on a PHP variable to change and localize the output

Tags: php

how can I change the output of the following to something like `2 hours and 30 minutes`?

The current output is `'hours':02,'mins':30`

Also how can I change hours to my language? (greek)

```
function time_difference($endtime){
    $times=array(
        'hours' => date("G",$endtime),
        'mins' => date("i",$endtime),
    );

    //added a "just a moment ago" feature for you
    if (intval($times['hours'], 10) == 0 
           && intval($times['mins'], 10) == 0) {
        return "just a moment ago";
    } 

    $diff='';
    foreach ($times as $k=>$v) {
        $diff.=empty($diff) ? '' : ',';
        $diff.=intval($v, 10) == 0 ? '' : "'$k':$v";
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
<?php


$strings = array(
                    "EN" => array("hours", "mins", "and")
                ,   "GR" => array("ώρες", "λεπτά", "και")
        );



$lang = "GR";


function time_difference($endtime){
    global $lang;
    global $strings;
    $times=array(
        $strings[$lang][0] => date("G",$endtime),
        $strings[$lang][1] => date("i",$endtime),
    );

    //added a "just a moment ago" feature for you
    if (intval($times[$strings[$lang][0]], 10) == 0 
           && intval($times[$strings[$lang][1]], 10) == 0) {
        return "just a moment ago";
    } 


  $diff='';
    foreach ($times as $k=>$v) {
        $diff.=empty($diff) ? '' : ' '. $strings[$lang][2] . ' ';
        $diff.=intval($v, 10) == 0 ? '' : "$v $k";
    }

    return $diff;
}   


echo time_difference(mktime(2, 32, 2, 6, 6, 2006));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 'hours' and 'minutes' into variables, write them down in a file and pull that file according to language.

Example for Portuguese file:

`/lg/pt/lg_time.php`

```
// each file will have the translation
define("HOURS", "horas");
define("MINUTES", "minutos");
```

Then, you just include the proper file in your applicatio.

Comment: @Punkis, you're welcome! Apparently someone though it was a really terrible one but did not care to comment. If the downvoter reads this please advice on how this should be done. Thanks!